# Merging different branches on git

Tags: git

I am working on a team project using git. I created a new branch to write my code. My colleagues as well. I want to integrate the code one of my colleagues developed to my branch without he needs to merge it with the master: Is it possible to merge two branches without merging them to the master?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`master` is just some more-or-less random branch as well. You can merge any branch into *any other* branch—not just into master. To do that, check out the target branch and then call `git merge` on the branch you want to merge in.

So when trying to merge into master, you first check out master using `git checkout master` and then you merge your branch `git merge yourbranch`. If you want to merge it into that colleague’s branch, you check out that first and then merge your branch:

```
git checkout otherbranch
git merge yourbranch
```